# Rails/React flatpickr momentjs time conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, reactjs, momentjs, flatpickr

I have a rails/react app (just one app) in which a user is allowed to schedule a meeting using [Flatpickr](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr) .

I am passing down a datetime column called "scheduled_for" so that I can use it in my react component.

This is what my "componentDidMount()" looks like:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    new Flatpickr(this.refs.scheduledFor, {
      minDate: new Date(),
      enableTime: true,
      altInput: true,
      altFormat: "F j, Y h:i K", 
      onChange: function(dateObject) { console.log(dateObject) }
    });
  }
```

There is a "scheduled_for_future" validation method in my Meeting model to prevent the meeting from being scheduled in the past.

```
##app/models/meeting.rb

validate :scheduled_for_future

def scheduled_for_future 
  if scheduled_for.present? && scheduled_for < Time.zone.now
    errors.add(:scheduled_for, "Must be in future")
  end
end
```

I want a user to be able to pick a date & time in their local time zone and have it be saved as UTC (the Heroku default).

Everything works fine on local dev but if I try to pick a time & date in production, say for example 10 minutes from now, I get the "Must be in the future" error. (this obviously occurs because my Timezone is PT and 10 minutes from now is in the past according to the server's time)

It feels like this should be simple to fix. For the sake of UX I want the client to be able to pick the time in their own time zone and have convert to UTC before saving, but just can't figure it out.

I'm not very experienced with momentjs or flatpickr so it's likely that I'm missing something very important.

Please let me know if you need any more info/ something doesn't make sense.

thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment to format the datetime on the client side to include the timezone offset. `currDate`, in your case would be the datetime selected in your Flatpickr calendar.

```
var currDate = new Date();
console.log("Current Date: " + moment(currDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ"));

// Returns ...
Current Date: 2017-02-25 09:38:02-05:00
```

Then you can pass that to up rails, as a string, and convert it to UTC before persisting in the database

```
2.3.1 :003 > client_date = "2017-02-25 09:38:02-05:00"
 => "2017-02-25 09:38:02-05:00" 
2.3.1 :004 > utc_date = Time.zone.parse(client_date).utc
 => 2017-02-25 14:38:02 UTC
```